# Encoding images to webp on iOS regardless of the color space?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, color-space, webp

I'm trying to convert any picture to WebP on the fly but I have a lot of trouble with images that have a color space that isn't RGB: it's grayscale (kCGColorSpaceModelMonochrome).

Is there an existing WebP library or class that will convert non-RGB images to WebP?
Or is there any way I can convert a non-RGB image to an RGB image programmatically so I can modify the WebP class that I already have?

Thanks!

Comment: What colorspaces are you dealing with? Grayscale? HSV? Y'CbCr? CMYK?

Comment: @user1118321 I've had to deal with grayscale (kCGColorSpaceModelMonochrome) and RGB up to now.

Converting a picture from grayscale to RGB shouldn't be complicated, right?

Comment: No, not at all. If you have a bitmap of the grayscale image, you can just copy the grayscale value to all 3 channels (red, green, and blue) in a new bitmap and you'll have an RGB image that looks the same.

Comment: You are probably better off converting whatever you have (monochrome) into YUVA
cause that was google's webp.framework converts to anyway.

Comment: Actually that seems to apply only to the losy encoding path: // Main flag for encoder selecting between ARGB or YUV input.
  // It is recommended to use ARGB input (*argb, argb_stride) for lossless
  // compression, and YUV input (*y, *u, *v, etc.) for lossy compression
  // since these are the respective native colorspace for these formats.